# Changing elements positions with sql database

Tags: php, sql, sqlite, sorting, web-applications

I have element with `position` property. So that you can select them with `ORDER BY pos`

```
item | pos
aaa  | 1
bbb  | 2
ccc  | 3
```

and change them to

```
item | pos
aaa  | 2
bbb  | 3
ccc  | 1
```

What is the common way to work with changing positioning?
I am using PHP+SQLite, but I think it doesn't matter.

All I can think about is changing them step by step, swapping every two adjusted things. But it will be messy if they are not adjust, for example, changing element with position x to position 1.

What is the common practices for this? Or what are the keywords for googling it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found http://jqueryui.com/sortable/ . It can be used to rearrange and then bulk update database values. Sounds like a solution, I will try it.

It has nice `serialize( options )` for passing a new order to a server script.